# Разные шаблоны для фронтенда

Tags: laravel, маршрутизация

Cтолкнулся с такой проблемой:

Необходимо для каждого пункта основного топ меню(5 ссылок) генерировать разные лефт меню. Элементы берутся из бд( категории, жанры)... Нашел способ с использованием `SerivceProvider`-а и `ViewComposer`-а.

Можно ли в этом `ViewComposer` взять имя контроллера, и префикс текущего роута??? в доках для `Illuminate\Routing\Route` есть методы `getController` и  `getPrefix` но  их не смог использовать в `ViewComposer`-е.

Comment: Вы использовали class based composers или closure based composers? (см. https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/views#view-composers)

Answer (score 0):

Я использовал отдельный класс. Спустя нескольких дней поисков вроде нашел решение...
$controller = class_basename($action['controller']); - этой строкой беру контроллер и его экшен. Далее проверяю нужные мне контроллеры и передаю соответствующие данные на вю 
$view->with('for','books')->with('data',Janr::all());